# Compare values then store IP and jump Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to create an assembly program that compares a variable to 0 and jumps if it is lower than 0:

```
mov eax, [ebx]
cmp eax, 0
jl input1
```

However, I am jumping to a label that has **ret** so it needs the location of where to go back to when the subroutine is completed. How can I find the current location of the instruction pointer and push it to the stack before I jump ?

Here is input1 subroutine:

```
            input1:
            push inputnumber
            lea eax, inputmsg
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 8

            push ebx
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call scanf
            add esp, 8  
            ret
```

Comment: The `call` instruction does what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, my bad, fixed it - jumps if it is smaller than 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `call`. Since there is no conditional version, use a reversed conditional jump to skip it. E.g.

```
mov eax, [ebx]
cmp eax, 0
jge skip ; reversed jl
call input1
skip:
...
```

If it's supposed to be a range check loop, something like:

```
do {
    inputnumber = input1();
} while (inputnumber < 0 || inputnumber > 100);
```

Then you can do:

```
repeat:
    call input1
    mov eax, [inputnumber]
    cmp eax, 0
    jl repeat
    cmp eax, 100
    jg repeat
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have to compare once if below 0 and once if above 100. Where do I put the skip then ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do. Apply conditional branches and `call` as required. Draw a flowchart if confused.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Got it working. Thanks again :)

Comment: Signed range checks are best done using an unsigned compare, so values that are too low appear as unsigned above.  e.g. in this case, `cmp eax, 100` / `ja repeat`.  If the bottom of the range wasn't zero, then `lea ecx, [eax - 20]` / `cmp ecx, 80` / `ja repeat` to keep looping until eax is in the `20..100` range.